# Getting parse error while fetching text file content in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I am trying to fetch data from text file which resides on server. I have access of that location and able to see content when I put URL in browser tab.
I am trying to make AJAX call and get file content, but I am getting Error: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**

Code

```
    function logResults(json){
  console.log(json);
}

$.ajax({
  url: u,
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonpCallback: "logResults"
});
```

[image]

on console,
[image]

I tried below code too, but same result,

```
     $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: u,
   crossDomain: true,
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   async: false,
   headers: {
     "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
     },
   success: function(succ) {
     console.log("Success: ", succ)
   },
   error: function(err) {
     console.log("Error: ", err)
   }
 });
```

This code is always going into error block.

Comment: does the server actually return `jsonp` - or are you desperately trying all the usual "tricks" to circumvent CORS issues ... CORS is controlled **by the  server** ... adding `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` shows that you don't know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> ```
> dataType: "jsonp",
> ```

But the URL is responding with:

> Deployment automatically finished…

Which is **not** JSONP, it is plain text.

You get the error when it tries to execute the plain text as JSONP.

**Don't put wrong information in the `dataType` field**.

---

> ```
> async: false,
> ```

That's deprecated. Don't use it. It's also pointless since you are using callbacks.

It's also incompatible with JSONP so it is ignored (until you remove the incorrect `dataType`).

---

> crossDomain: true,

This has no effect unless you are making a:

- non-JSONP request
- to the *same* origin
- which gets redirected to a *different* origin

… which is very rare.

---

> ```
> headers: {
>     "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
>  },
> ```

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header. It doesn't belong the request. Trying to add it to the request will cause extra problems as it will make the request preflighted.

(At least, that would be the case if you hadn't said `dataType: 'jsonp'` because adding request headers is incompatible with JSONP).

---

## All you need on the client

The only code you need on the client is:

```
function logResults(result){
   console.log(result);
}

$.ajax({
    url: u,
    success: logResults
});
```

The **server** you are requesting the data from will need to use [CORS to grant you permission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068) to access it  if it is a cross-origin request.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have added **dataType as jsonp**, so that it will try to parse the response to JSON and if the response is not a JSON it will throw error.

Comment: `it will try to parse the response to JSON` -actually it won't ... it will load it as a `<script>` - but other than that  everything up to the `,` is correct

Comment: it will fail - since JSON isn't valid javascript (though, if the data is an array, it may not throw an error since it's possible to have a statement in javascript like `[]`

Comment: Understood bro, it expects a script right

Comment: it actually expects something like `function xyz() { return something_that_is_valid_in_javascript }` and the underlying code will call `result = xyz()` ... that's when the error would happen if the JSON response was parsable as javascript, since there was no function

Comment: It expects `name_of_callback_function_passed_in_url({some: "data", that: "is usually an object literal", here: true });` and jQuery (or whatever JSONP library) will have created `window.name_of_callback_function_passed_in_url` when it made the request.  In the OP's version, they are overriding the auto function generation with `logResults` which isn't good for handling parallel requests.